# How to display a specific attribute name and value beside a node in JTree?

Tags: java, xml, swing, xml-parsing, jtree

I want to display the name and values of an attribute beside the node name in `JTree`. Can anyone tell me how to do that? Here is the code I use to display the `JTree`:

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.Event.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.tree.*;
import org.xml.sax.*;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.*;
import org.apache.xerces.parsers.*;

public class XMLTreeView {

    private SAXTreeBuilder saxTree = null;
    private static String file = "";

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("XMLTreeView: [ games.xml ]");
        frame.setSize(400, 400);

        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent ev) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        file = "example1.xml";
        new XMLTreeView(frame);
    }

    public XMLTreeView(JFrame frame) {
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        DefaultMutableTreeNode top = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(file);
//              DefaultMutableTreeNode top = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("XML Document"); 
        saxTree = new SAXTreeBuilder(top);
        try {
            SAXParser saxParser = new SAXParser();
            saxParser.setContentHandler(saxTree);
            saxParser.parse(new InputSource(new FileInputStream(file)));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            top.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(ex.getMessage()));
        }
        JTree tree = new JTree(saxTree.getTree());
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(tree);

        frame.getContentPane().add("Center", scrollPane);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class SAXTreeBuilder extends DefaultHandler {

    private DefaultMutableTreeNode currentNode = null;
    private DefaultMutableTreeNode previousNode = null;
    private DefaultMutableTreeNode rootNode = null;

    public SAXTreeBuilder(DefaultMutableTreeNode root) {
        rootNode = root;
    }

    public void startDocument() {
        currentNode = rootNode;
    }

    public void endDocument() {
    }

    public void characters(char[] data, int start, int end) {
        String str = new String(data, start, end);
        if (!str.equals("") && Character.isLetter(str.charAt(0))) {
            currentNode.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(str));
        }
    }

    public void startElement(String uri, String qName, String lName, Attributes atts) {
        previousNode = currentNode;
        currentNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(lName);
        // Add attributes as child nodes //
        attachAttributeList(currentNode, atts);
        previousNode.add(currentNode);
    }

    public void endElement(String uri, String qName, String lName) {
        if (currentNode.getUserObject().equals(lName)) {
            currentNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) currentNode.getParent();
        }
    }

    public DefaultMutableTreeNode getTree() {
        return rootNode;
    }

    private void attachAttributeList(DefaultMutableTreeNode node, Attributes atts) {
        for (int i = 0; i < atts.getLength(); i++) {
            String name = atts.getLocalName(i);
            String value = atts.getValue(name);
            node.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(name + " = " + value));
        }
    }
}
```

In the `JTree`, I want to display the `NEType` attribute beside `NE` node,and the `equipmentHolderType` attribute beside `EQHO` node

```
NE NEType=WBTS
    EQHO equipmentHolderType=Subrack
```

I want to have somthing like this:

[image]

Here is an example of xml files that I deal with :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes" ?> 
<HWData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="hw_data.xsd">
<Header xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance" AdaptationName="NWI3BulkUpload" AccessProtocol="NWI3" time="2004-01-01T00:04:02" uploaded="true" version="1.0" /> 
<NE xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance" vendorName="Nokia Siemens Networks" objectClass="NE" objectClassVersion="1" MOID="NE-RNC-1/DN:NE-WBTS-4183" NEId="PLMN-PLMN/RNC-1/WBTS-4183" NEType="WBTS" operationalState="enabled" locationName="Tun4183" nameFromPlanningSystem="" systemTitle="Nokia Flexi WCDMA Base Station">
<EQHO vendorName="Nokia Siemens Networks" objectClass="EQHO" objectClassVersion="1" MOID="NE-RNC-1/DN:NE-WBTS-4183/EQHO-40448" equipmentHolderId="40448" equipmentHolderType="Subrack" equipmentHolderSpecificType="472100A-40448" identificationCode="472100A" version="101" serialNumber="K9111641678" userLabel="FRGP" state="working">
<UNIT vendorName="Nokia Siemens Networks" objectClass="UNIT" objectClassVersion="1" MOID="NE-RNC-1/DN:NE-WBTS-4183/EQHO-40448/UNIT-158" unitId="158" unitTypeActual="CORE_FRGP" identificationCode="084629A" version="101" serialNumber="K9111641678" /> 
</EQHO>
<EQHO vendorName="Nokia Siemens Networks" objectClass="EQHO" objectClassVersion="1" MOID="NE-RNC-1/DN:NE-WBTS-4183/EQHO-173" equipmentHolderId="173" equipmentHolderType="Subrack" equipmentHolderSpecificType="471469A-173" identificationCode="471469A" version="" serialNumber="L1104816112" userLabel="FSME" state="working">
<UNIT vendorName="N" objectClass="UNIT" objectClassVersion="1" MOID="NE-RNC-1/DN:NE-WBTS-4183/EQHO-173/UNIT-16" unitId="16" unitTypeActual="CORE_FSME" identificationCode="083833A" version="104" serialNumber="L1104816112" /> 
<UNIT vendorName="NOKIA SIEMENS NETWORKS" objectClass="UNIT" objectClassVersion="1" MOID="NE-RNC-1/DN:NE-WBTS-4183/EQHO-173/UNIT-225" unitId="225" unitTypeActual="FTLB" identificationCode="471984A" version="103" serialNumber="RY104807867" /> 
</EQHO>
<EQHO vendorName="NSN" objectClass="EQHO" objectClassVersion="1" MOID="NE-RNC-1/DN:NE-WBTS-4183/EQHO-40192" equipmentHolderId="40192" equipmentHolderType="Subrack" equipmentHolderSpecificType="472083A-40192" identificationCode="472083A" version="101" serialNumber="L6105220714" userLabel="FXDA" state="working" /> 
</NE>
</HWData>
```

Comment: Are you having trouble building the [`TreeModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html#data) or accessing that model in your [`TreeCellRenderer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html#display)? Please edit your question to include a [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits any problem you encounter.

Comment: no i have no touble with the code if u try to execute the code in ur machine it will generate the jtree without what i wrote on strong in the picture..what i am seeking for is how to modify the code in order to display the jtree like in the picture !!

Comment: What happens with the code you posted? The recommended way is to compose the text in a custom `TreeCellRenderer`.

Comment: hey @trashgod um using that code to display the jtree without using TreeCellRenderer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could change the string that is used to construct the tree node:

```
public void startElement(String uri, String qName, String lName, Attributes atts) {
    previousNode = currentNode;
    // Use the result of the getNodeText method to construct the tree node.
    currentNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(getNodeText(lName, atts));
    // Add attributes as child nodes //
    attachAttributeList(currentNode, atts);
    previousNode.add(currentNode);
}

private String getNodeText(final String lName, final Attributes atts) {
    final String postfix;

    if ("NE".equals(lName) && atts.getValue("NEType") != null)
        postfix = " NEType=" + atts.getValue("NEType");
    else if ("EQHO".equals(lName) && atts.getValue("equipmentHolderType") != null)
        postfix = " equipmentHolderType=" + atts.getValue("equipmentHolderType");
    else
        postfix = "";

    return lName + postfix;
}
```

This is the complete code I ran:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;

import org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser;
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class XMLTreeView {
    private SAXTreeBuilder saxTree = null;
    private static String file = "";

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        file = "etc\\q29921994\\example2.xml";
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("XMLTreeView: [ " + file.substring(file.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1) + " ]");
        frame.setSize(400, 400);

        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent ev) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        new XMLTreeView(frame);
    }

    public XMLTreeView(JFrame frame) {
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        DefaultMutableTreeNode top = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(file);
        //    DefaultMutableTreeNode top = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("XML Document");
        saxTree = new SAXTreeBuilder(top);

        try {
            SAXParser saxParser = new SAXParser();
            saxParser.setContentHandler(saxTree);
            saxParser.parse(new InputSource(new FileInputStream(file)));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            top.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(ex.getMessage()));
        }
        JTree tree = new JTree(saxTree.getTree());
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(tree);

        frame.getContentPane().add("Center", scrollPane);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}


class SAXTreeBuilder extends DefaultHandler {
    private DefaultMutableTreeNode currentNode = null;
    private DefaultMutableTreeNode previousNode = null;
    private DefaultMutableTreeNode rootNode = null;

    public SAXTreeBuilder(DefaultMutableTreeNode root) {
        rootNode = root;
    }

    public void startDocument() {
        currentNode = rootNode;
    }

    public void endDocument() {
    }

    public void characters(char[] data, int start, int end) {
        String str = new String(data, start, end);
        if (!str.equals("") && Character.isLetter(str.charAt(0)))
            currentNode.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(str));
    }

    public void startElement(String uri, String qName, String lName, Attributes atts) {
        previousNode = currentNode;
        // currentNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(lName);
        // Use the result of the getNodeText method to construct the tree node.
        currentNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(getNodeText(lName, atts));
        // Add attributes as child nodes //
        attachAttributeList(currentNode, atts);
        previousNode.add(currentNode);
    }

    public void endElement(String uri, String qName, String lName) {
        // I think the if below can be removed:
        //if (currentNode.getUserObject().equals(lName))
            currentNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) currentNode.getParent();
    }

    private String getNodeText(final String lName, final Attributes atts) {
        final String postfix;

        if ("NE".equals(lName) && atts.getValue("NEType") != null)
            postfix = " NEType=" + atts.getValue("NEType");
        else if ("EQHO".equals(lName) && atts.getValue("equipmentHolderType") != null)
            postfix = " equipmentHolderType=" + atts.getValue("equipmentHolderType");
        else if ("UNIT".equals(lName) && atts.getValue("unitTypeActual") != null)
            postfix = " equipmentHolderType=" + atts.getValue("unitTypeActual");
        else if ("FUUT".equals(lName) && atts.getValue("functionalUnitType") != null)
            postfix = " equipmentHolderType=" + atts.getValue("functionalUnitType");
        else
            postfix = "";

        return lName + postfix;
    }

    public DefaultMutableTreeNode getTree() {
        return rootNode;
    }

    private void attachAttributeList(DefaultMutableTreeNode node, Attributes atts) {
        for (int i = 0; i < atts.getLength(); i++) {
            String name = atts.getLocalName(i);
            String value = atts.getValue(name);
            node.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(name + " = " + value));
        }
    }
}
```

This is the example2.xml file I used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
<HWData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="hw_data.xsd">
    <Header xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance" AdaptationName="NWI3BulkUpload" AccessProtocol="NWI3" time="2013-05-29T13:09:29" uploaded="true" version="1.0"/>
    <NE xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance" vendorName="Nokia Siemens Networks" objectClass="NE" objectClassVersion="1" MOID="NE-RNC-4/DN:NE-WBTS-4204" NEId="PLMN-PLMN/RNC-4/WBTS-4204" NEType="WBTS" operationalState="enabled" locationName="SFX4204" nameFromPlanningSystem="" systemTitle="Nokia Flexi WCDMA Base Station">
        <EQHO vendorName="Nokia Siemens Networks" objectClass="EQHO" objectClassVersion="1" MOID="NE-RNC-4/DN:NE-WBTS-4204/EQHO-173" equipmentHolderId="173" equipmentHolderType="Subrack" equipmentHolderSpecificType="471469A-173" identificationCode="471469A" version="" serialNumber="F7123009045" userLabel="FSME" state="working">
            <UNIT vendorName="N" objectClass="UNIT" objectClassVersion="1" MOID="NE-RNC-4/DN:NE-WBTS-4204/EQHO-173/UNIT-16" unitId="16" unitTypeActual="CORE_FSME" identificationCode="083833A" version="105" serialNumber="F7123009045"/>
            <UNIT vendorName="NOKIA SIEMENS NETWORKS" objectClass="UNIT" objectClassVersion="1" MOID="NE-RNC-4/DN:NE-WBTS-4204/EQHO-173/UNIT-225" unitId="225" unitTypeActual="FTLB" identificationCode="471984A" version="104" serialNumber="K9123412124"/>
        </EQHO>
        <EQHO vendorName="NSN" objectClass="EQHO" objectClassVersion="1" MOID="NE-RNC-4/DN:NE-WBTS-4204/EQHO-40192" equipmentHolderId="40192" equipmentHolderType="Subrack" equipmentHolderSpecificType="472083A-40192" identificationCode="472083A" version="203" serialNumber="K9123021259" userLabel="FXDA" state="working">
            <UNIT vendorName="AR" objectClass="UNIT" objectClassVersion="1" MOID="NE-RNC-4/DN:NE-WBTS-4204/EQHO-40192/UNIT-56081" unitId="56081" unitTypeActual="TILT" identificationCode="CV3PX310R-BTQ" version="" serialNumber="00000008496310581"/>
            <UNIT vendorName="AR" objectClass="UNIT" objectClassVersion="1" MOID="NE-RNC-4/DN:NE-WBTS-4204/EQHO-40192/UNIT-56083" unitId="56083" unitTypeActual="TILT" identificationCode="CV3PX310R-BTQ" version="" serialNumber="00000008496310721"/>
            <UNIT vendorName="AR" objectClass="UNIT" objectClassVersion="1" MOID="NE-RNC-4/DN:NE-WBTS-4204/EQHO-40192/UNIT-56085" unitId="56085" unitTypeActual="TILT" identificationCode="CV3PX310R-BTQ" version="" serialNumber="00000008496310441"/>
        </EQHO>
        <EQHO vendorName="AR" objectClass="EQHO" objectClassVersion="1" MOID="NE-RNC-4/DN:NE-WBTS-4204/EQHO-56089" equipmentHolderId="56089" equipmentHolderType="Subrack" equipmentHolderSpecificType="CV3PX310R-BTQ-56089" identificationCode="CV3PX310R-BTQ" version="" serialNumber="00000008496310584" userLabel="" state="working"/>
        <EQHO vendorName="AR" objectClass="EQHO" objectClassVersion="1" MOID="NE-RNC-4/DN:NE-WBTS-4204/EQHO-56090" equipmentHolderId="56090" equipmentHolderType="Subrack" equipmentHolderSpecificType="CV3PX310R-BTQ-56090" identificationCode="CV3PX310R-BTQ" version="" serialNumber="00000008496310582" userLabel="" state="working"/>
        <EQHO vendorName="AR" objectClass="EQHO" objectClassVersion="1" MOID="NE-RNC-4/DN:NE-WBTS-4204/EQHO-56091" equipmentHolderId="56091" equipmentHolderType="Subrack" equipmentHolderSpecificType="CV3PX310R-BTQ-56091" identificationCode="CV3PX310R-BTQ" version="" serialNumber="00000008496310724" userLabel="" state="working"/>
        <EQHO vendorName="AR" objectClass="EQHO" objectClassVersion="1" MOID="NE-RNC-4/DN:NE-WBTS-4204/EQHO-56092" equipmentHolderId="56092" equipmentHolderType="Subrack" equipmentHolderSpecificType="CV3PX310R-BTQ-56092" identificationCode="CV3PX310R-BTQ" version="" serialNumber="00000008496310722" userLabel="" state="working"/>
        <EQHO vendorName="AR" objectClass="EQHO" objectClassVersion="1" MOID="NE-RNC-4/DN:NE-WBTS-4204/EQHO-56093" equipmentHolderId="56093" equipmentHolderType="Subrack" equipmentHolderSpecificType="CV3PX310R-BTQ-56093" identificationCode="CV3PX310R-BTQ" version="" serialNumber="00000008496310444" userLabel="" state="working"/>
        <EQHO vendorName="AR" objectClass="EQHO" objectClassVersion="1" MOID="NE-RNC-4/DN:NE-WBTS-4204/EQHO-56094" equipmentHolderId="56094" equipmentHolderType="Subrack" equipmentHolderSpecificType="CV3PX310R-BTQ-56094" identificationCode="CV3PX310R-BTQ" version="" serialNumber="00000008496310442" userLabel="" state="working"/>
        <EQHO vendorName="Nokia Siemens Networks" objectClass="EQHO" objectClassVersion="1" MOID="NE-RNC-4/DN:NE-WBTS-4204/EQHO-40448" equipmentHolderId="40448" equipmentHolderType="Subrack" equipmentHolderSpecificType="472100A-40448" identificationCode="472100A" version="101" serialNumber="K9122905970" userLabel="FRGP" state="working">
            <UNIT vendorName="Nokia Siemens Networks" objectClass="UNIT" objectClassVersion="1" MOID="NE-RNC-4/DN:NE-WBTS-4204/EQHO-40448/UNIT-158" unitId="158" unitTypeActual="CORE_FRGP" identificationCode="084629A" version="101" serialNumber="K9122905970"/>
            <UNIT vendorName="AR" objectClass="UNIT" objectClassVersion="1" MOID="NE-RNC-4/DN:NE-WBTS-4204/EQHO-40448/UNIT-56593" unitId="56593" unitTypeActual="TILT" identificationCode="CV3PX310R-BTQ" version="" serialNumber="00000008496310583"/>
            <UNIT vendorName="AR" objectClass="UNIT" objectClassVersion="1" MOID="NE-RNC-4/DN:NE-WBTS-4204/EQHO-40448/UNIT-56595" unitId="56595" unitTypeActual="TILT" identificationCode="CV3PX310R-BTQ" version="" serialNumber="00000008496310723"/>
            <UNIT vendorName="AR" objectClass="UNIT" objectClassVersion="1" MOID="NE-RNC-4/DN:NE-WBTS-4204/EQHO-40448/UNIT-56597" unitId="56597" unitTypeActual="TILT" identificationCode="CV3PX310R-BTQ" version="" serialNumber="00000008496310443"/>
        </EQHO>
    </NE>
</HWData>
```

This is the screenshot of the running program:

[image: Screenshot from modified program]

Comment: hey Freek my goal is not to display the attribute strongly .. i just wrote it that way to make it clear ..what i want to know is how to make jtree display a specific attribute besides the node name ( the attribute is one of the node's attributes)

Comment: Changed the answer after initially misunderstanding the question.

Comment: Hi Freek, i faced problems using this..the jtree is not properly displayed ..now every node is shown under the node above it even it is not its parent !! what i have to do to fix that ??

Comment: That sounds very strange. Could you add your changed code and a new screenshot to your question, because I don't see the problem you're describing.

Comment: so is there a way that fix that issue ?

Comment: Looking at your changed code (in the other answer), it is not clear to me why every node is shown under the previous node. Could you add the xml file you used in that case (with nodes that have equipmentHolderType = TILT)? The `attachAttributeList` method has the line that adds a node to another node disabled. This removes all leaf nodes from the tree and only the branch nodes remain.

Comment: hey @Freek i have already added the xml file (in the other answer) that i used !!

Comment: I can't find TILT in that xml file.

Comment: aah so it was a mistake when i was trying to show the the attribute name and value i forgot to change the attribute name to  "unitTypeActual" for the units tag..it should be  "unitTypeActual" not "equipmentHolderType" for units

Comment: but still have the same problem :\

Comment: i added a new screen shot at the top of the answer

Comment: I think the `endElement` method needs your attention. Because the node text is now extended, the comparison to the `lName` no longer works correctly in many cases. Why is the if necessary?

Comment: the if is necessary because i have to display a specific attribute name and value for each type of nodes !

Answer (score 3):

In the variation below, I've used `javax.xml.parsers`, a modified `getNodeText()` and your updated `xml`.

[image]

`XMLTreeView.java`:

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.tree.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

/** @see http://stackoverflow.com/q/29921994/230513 */
public class XMLTreeView {

    private static final String file = "example.xml";

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            new XMLTreeView();
        });
    }

    public XMLTreeView() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("XMLTreeView: [ games.xml ]");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        DefaultMutableTreeNode top = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(file);
        SAXTreeBuilder saxTree = new SAXTreeBuilder(top);
        try {
            SAXParserFactory parserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser saxParser = parserFactory.newSAXParser();
            saxParser.parse(file, saxTree);
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
        JTree tree = new JTree(saxTree.getTree());
        tree.expandRow(1);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(tree);
        frame.add(scrollPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class SAXTreeBuilder extends DefaultHandler {

    private DefaultMutableTreeNode rootNode;
    private DefaultMutableTreeNode currentNode;
    private DefaultMutableTreeNode previousNode;

    public SAXTreeBuilder(DefaultMutableTreeNode root) {
        rootNode = root;
    }

    @Override
    public void startDocument() {
        currentNode = rootNode;
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String qName, String lName, Attributes atts) {
        previousNode = currentNode;
        currentNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(getNodeText(lName, atts));
        attachAttributeList(currentNode, atts);
        previousNode.add(currentNode);
    }

    private String getNodeText(final String lName, final Attributes atts) {
        if ("NE".equals(lName)) {
            return lName + " NEType=" + atts.getValue("NEType");
        } else if ("EQHO".equals(lName)) {
            return lName + " equipmentHolderType=" + atts.getValue("equipmentHolderType");
        } else if ("UNIT".equals(lName)) {
            return lName + " equipmentHolderType=" + atts.getValue("unitTypeActual");
        } else if ("FUUT".equals(lName)) {
            return lName + " equipmentHolderType=" + atts.getValue("functionalUnitType");
        } else {
            return lName;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String qName, String lName) {
        if (currentNode.getUserObject().equals(lName)) {
            currentNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) currentNode.getParent();
        }
    }

    public DefaultMutableTreeNode getTree() {
        return rootNode;
    }

    private void attachAttributeList(DefaultMutableTreeNode node, Attributes atts) {
        for (int i = 0; i < atts.getLength(); i++) {
            String name = atts.getLocalName(i);
            String value = atts.getValue(name);
            node.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(name + " = " + value));
        }
    }
}
```

`example.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
<HWData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="hw_data.xsd">
<Header xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance" AdaptationName="NWI3BulkUpload" AccessProtocol="NWI3" time="2013-05-29T13:09:29" uploaded="true" version="1.0"/>
<NE xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance" vendorName="Nokia Siemens Networks" objectClass="NE" objectClassVersion="1" MOID="NE-RNC-4/DN:NE-WBTS-4204" NEId="PLMN-PLMN/RNC-4/WBTS-4204" NEType="WBTS" operationalState="enabled" locationName="SFX4204" nameFromPlanningSystem="" systemTitle="Nokia Flexi WCDMA Base Station">
<EQHO vendorName="Nokia Siemens Networks" objectClass="EQHO" objectClassVersion="1" MOID="NE-RNC-4/DN:NE-WBTS-4204/EQHO-173" equipmentHolderId="173" equipmentHolderType="Subrack" equipmentHolderSpecificType="471469A-173" identificationCode="471469A" version="" serialNumber="F7123009045" userLabel="FSME" state="working">
<UNIT vendorName="N" objectClass="UNIT" objectClassVersion="1" MOID="NE-RNC-4/DN:NE-WBTS-4204/EQHO-173/UNIT-16" unitId="16" unitTypeActual="CORE_FSME" identificationCode="083833A" version="105" serialNumber="F7123009045"/>
<UNIT vendorName="NOKIA SIEMENS NETWORKS" objectClass="UNIT" objectClassVersion="1" MOID="NE-RNC-4/DN:NE-WBTS-4204/EQHO-173/UNIT-225" unitId="225" unitTypeActual="FTLB" identificationCode="471984A" version="104" serialNumber="K9123412124"/>
</EQHO>
<EQHO vendorName="NSN" objectClass="EQHO" objectClassVersion="1" MOID="NE-RNC-4/DN:NE-WBTS-4204/EQHO-40192" equipmentHolderId="40192" equipmentHolderType="Subrack" equipmentHolderSpecificType="472083A-40192" identificationCode="472083A" version="203" serialNumber="K9123021259" userLabel="FXDA" state="working">
<UNIT vendorName="AR" objectClass="UNIT" objectClassVersion="1" MOID="NE-RNC-4/DN:NE-WBTS-4204/EQHO-40192/UNIT-56081" unitId="56081" unitTypeActual="TILT" identificationCode="CV3PX310R-BTQ" version="" serialNumber="00000008496310581"/>
<UNIT vendorName="AR" objectClass="UNIT" objectClassVersion="1" MOID="NE-RNC-4/DN:NE-WBTS-4204/EQHO-40192/UNIT-56083" unitId="56083" unitTypeActual="TILT" identificationCode="CV3PX310R-BTQ" version="" serialNumber="00000008496310721"/>
<UNIT vendorName="AR" objectClass="UNIT" objectClassVersion="1" MOID="NE-RNC-4/DN:NE-WBTS-4204/EQHO-40192/UNIT-56085" unitId="56085" unitTypeActual="TILT" identificationCode="CV3PX310R-BTQ" version="" serialNumber="00000008496310441"/>
</EQHO>
<EQHO vendorName="AR" objectClass="EQHO" objectClassVersion="1" MOID="NE-RNC-4/DN:NE-WBTS-4204/EQHO-56089" equipmentHolderId="56089" equipmentHolderType="Subrack" equipmentHolderSpecificType="CV3PX310R-BTQ-56089" identificationCode="CV3PX310R-BTQ" version="" serialNumber="00000008496310584" userLabel="" state="working"/>
<EQHO vendorName="AR" objectClass="EQHO" objectClassVersion="1" MOID="NE-RNC-4/DN:NE-WBTS-4204/EQHO-56090" equipmentHolderId="56090" equipmentHolderType="Subrack" equipmentHolderSpecificType="CV3PX310R-BTQ-56090" identificationCode="CV3PX310R-BTQ" version="" serialNumber="00000008496310582" userLabel="" state="working"/>
<EQHO vendorName="AR" objectClass="EQHO" objectClassVersion="1" MOID="NE-RNC-4/DN:NE-WBTS-4204/EQHO-56091" equipmentHolderId="56091" equipmentHolderType="Subrack" equipmentHolderSpecificType="CV3PX310R-BTQ-56091" identificationCode="CV3PX310R-BTQ" version="" serialNumber="00000008496310724" userLabel="" state="working"/>
<EQHO vendorName="AR" objectClass="EQHO" objectClassVersion="1" MOID="NE-RNC-4/DN:NE-WBTS-4204/EQHO-56092" equipmentHolderId="56092" equipmentHolderType="Subrack" equipmentHolderSpecificType="CV3PX310R-BTQ-56092" identificationCode="CV3PX310R-BTQ" version="" serialNumber="00000008496310722" userLabel="" state="working"/>
<EQHO vendorName="AR" objectClass="EQHO" objectClassVersion="1" MOID="NE-RNC-4/DN:NE-WBTS-4204/EQHO-56093" equipmentHolderId="56093" equipmentHolderType="Subrack" equipmentHolderSpecificType="CV3PX310R-BTQ-56093" identificationCode="CV3PX310R-BTQ" version="" serialNumber="00000008496310444" userLabel="" state="working"/>
<EQHO vendorName="AR" objectClass="EQHO" objectClassVersion="1" MOID="NE-RNC-4/DN:NE-WBTS-4204/EQHO-56094" equipmentHolderId="56094" equipmentHolderType="Subrack" equipmentHolderSpecificType="CV3PX310R-BTQ-56094" identificationCode="CV3PX310R-BTQ" version="" serialNumber="00000008496310442" userLabel="" state="working"/>
<EQHO vendorName="Nokia Siemens Networks" objectClass="EQHO" objectClassVersion="1" MOID="NE-RNC-4/DN:NE-WBTS-4204/EQHO-40448" equipmentHolderId="40448" equipmentHolderType="Subrack" equipmentHolderSpecificType="472100A-40448" identificationCode="472100A" version="101" serialNumber="K9122905970" userLabel="FRGP" state="working">
<UNIT vendorName="Nokia Siemens Networks" objectClass="UNIT" objectClassVersion="1" MOID="NE-RNC-4/DN:NE-WBTS-4204/EQHO-40448/UNIT-158" unitId="158" unitTypeActual="CORE_FRGP" identificationCode="084629A" version="101" serialNumber="K9122905970"/>
<UNIT vendorName="AR" objectClass="UNIT" objectClassVersion="1" MOID="NE-RNC-4/DN:NE-WBTS-4204/EQHO-40448/UNIT-56593" unitId="56593" unitTypeActual="TILT" identificationCode="CV3PX310R-BTQ" version="" serialNumber="00000008496310583"/>
<UNIT vendorName="AR" objectClass="UNIT" objectClassVersion="1" MOID="NE-RNC-4/DN:NE-WBTS-4204/EQHO-40448/UNIT-56595" unitId="56595" unitTypeActual="TILT" identificationCode="CV3PX310R-BTQ" version="" serialNumber="00000008496310723"/>
<UNIT vendorName="AR" objectClass="UNIT" objectClassVersion="1" MOID="NE-RNC-4/DN:NE-WBTS-4204/EQHO-40448/UNIT-56597" unitId="56597" unitTypeActual="TILT" identificationCode="CV3PX310R-BTQ" version="" serialNumber="00000008496310443"/>
</EQHO>
</NE>
</HWData>
```