# JTree: How to add attributes of nodes as their own leaves?

Tags: java, xml, swing, tree, jtree

I'm visualizing XML files with `javax.swing.JTree`. Having used code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15964060/creating-a-jtree-out-of-an-xml-document-using-dom-parser) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29921994/how-to-display-a-specific-attribute-name-and-value-beside-a-node-in-jtree) question, I got stuck at adding attributes from a node as leaves to it.

This simple XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- comment -->
<MYXML xmlns="">
    <Header id=""></Header>
    <Product id="" name="">
        <Description>Some text</Description>
        <Ref id=""></Ref>
        <Data id="">
            <Ref id=""></Ref>
        </Data>
        <Form id=""></Form>
    </Product>
</MYXML>
```

is being parsed to `org.w3c.dom.Document` and passed as `org.w3c.dom.Node` to recursively build  a JTree:

```
private DefaultMutableTreeNode buildTreeNode(Node rootNode) {
    DefaultMutableTreeNode treeNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(
            rootNode.getNodeName());
    NodeList children = rootNode.getChildNodes();

    for (int i = 0; i < children.getLength(); i++) {
        Node node = children.item(i);
        short nodeType = node.getNodeType();

        if (nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            treeNode.add(buildTreeNode(node));

            // FIXME attributes should be leaves of their nodes
            if (node.hasAttributes()) {
                NamedNodeMap attributes = node.getAttributes();
                for (int j = 0; j < attributes.getLength(); j++) {
                    Node attr = attributes.item(j);
                    treeNode.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("@" + attr));
                }
            }
        } else if (nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
            String text = node.getTextContent().trim();
            if (!text.equals("")) {
                treeNode.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(text));
            }
        } else if (nodeType == Node.COMMENT_NODE) {
            String comment = node.getNodeValue().trim();
            treeNode.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("#" + comment));
        }
    }
    return treeNode;
}
```

The result is not what I wanted:

[image: result]

The leaves "Header", "Ref" and "Form" should be nodes and all attributes (marked `@`) should be the leaves of their nodes. How can I achieve this with my recursive approach?

Here is my working example on [Gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1602e973ac0dc764b1b9).

**EDIT**: I figured it out and answered my question below.

Comment: Maybe more like [this](http://www.developer.com/xml/article.php/3731356/Displaying-XML-in-a-Swing-JTree.htm)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I finally sorted it out, thanks to Krzysztof's hints. Now the nodes with children are handled correctly and attribute leaves are where they should be:

```
private DefaultMutableTreeNode buildTreeNode(Node rootNode) {
    DefaultMutableTreeNode treeNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(
            rootNode.getNodeName());

    if (rootNode.hasAttributes()) {
        NamedNodeMap attributes = rootNode.getAttributes();

        for (int j = 0; j < attributes.getLength(); j++) {
            String attr = attributes.item(j).toString();
            treeNode.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("@" + attr));
        }
    }

    if (rootNode.hasChildNodes()) {
        NodeList children = rootNode.getChildNodes();

        for (int i = 0; i < children.getLength(); i++) {
            Node node = children.item(i);
            short nodeType = node.getNodeType();

            if (nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
                treeNode.add(buildTreeNode(node));

            else if (nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
                String text = node.getTextContent().trim();
                if (!text.equals(""))
                    treeNode.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(text));

            } else if (nodeType == Node.COMMENT_NODE) {
                String comment = node.getNodeValue().trim();
                treeNode.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("#" + comment));
            }
        }
    }
    return treeNode;
```

Which produces what I wanted:

[image]

For completion, the corrected example on [Gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c345f24d389f3ce75ffd).

Answer (score 1):

There is a method isLeaf in TreeNode, you need to implement it, because, it normally return true, when this node has no childrens (childrenCount==0), and false otherwise. You would like to mark as node elements regardless of their children count, so you need to implement/override this method that it will return what you need.

Also there is a problem in your algorithm:

You need to check if your node has node childrens, or is only an end node with leafs. You need to distinguish this two, and implement proper logic for handling that, it is up to you, how you interpret this xml in your code.

Comment: Thanks, this did the job. It worked without calling `isLeaf()` since the logic is based on the document nodes (I should have named `rootNode` to `docNode` to make that clear).